# Spark 2.x: How to create custom RowEncoder to decode Oracle DataFrame to DataSet to avoid "AnalysisException: Cannot up cast ... as it may truncate"?

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp-with-timezone

TL;DR

**1)** `DataFrame` obtains a data from `Oracle` table - fields in DB are of `NUMBER` and `DATE` type, in DataFrame they turns to `decimal(38,10)` and `timestamp` types.
While applying implicit encoder, it happends an error:

```
    val ds = df.as[CaseClassName]
-----------
    "AnalysisException: Cannot up cast ... as it may truncate"
```

> **Workaround**:
>
> ```
> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType
> val ds = df.withColumn("dateColumn", df("timestampColumn").cast(DateType)).as[CaseClassName]
> ```

But it doesn't seem to be fully flexible solution - AFAIC it should be possible to create custom implicit `RowEncoder` without need of explicit call of `withColumn`. Does anybody know how to solve the task?

**2)** Is there a case to correctly convert the data from the field of `Oracle` type `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` to some scala type and back in `Spark`? How?

=================================================================

Detailed example for both cases:

Oracle part:

```
   create table info(
    numval number,
    decval number(10,2),
    strval varchar2(1000),
    dateval date,
    timestampval timestamp,
    timestampltzval timestamp with local time zone,
    nclobval nclob,
    xmltypeval xmltype 
    )
    insert into info values(1, 123.45, 'First field', sysdate, localtimestamp, current_timestamp, TO_NCLOB('This is first NCLOB message with symbol 牽'), xmltype('<book>some value</book>'));
    insert into info values(1, 123.45, 'Second field', sysdate+1, localtimestamp+1, current_timestamp+1, TO_NCLOB('This is second NCLOB message with symbol 牽'), xmltype('<book>some another value</book>'));
```

Spark part below. I have to comment and avoid fields of types TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, NCLOB, XMLTYPE because of Spark error. Error texts are shown in the listing.

```
    import java.security.Timestamp
    import java.sql.{Driver, Date, NClob}
    import java.util.Properties
    import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    import oracle.xdb.XMLType

object OraTest extends App {

      case class Info(
                        numval: Long,
                        decval: Double,
                        strval: String,
                        dateval: Date//,
                        //timestampval: Timestamp,
    /* Timestamp:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.security.Timestamp
      - field (class: "java.security.Timestamp", name: "timestampval")
      - root class: "OraTest.HitBm"
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:602)
    */
                        //timestampltzval: Timestamp// TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type -102 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:209)
                        //nclobval: NClob, // NCLOB: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type -102 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getCatalystType(JdbcUtils.scala:209)
                        //xmltypeval: String //XMLType
/*XMLType:        Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLNode
          at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor$XMLFactory.createXML(NamedTypeAccessor.java:118)
          at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getOracleObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:249)
          at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getString(NamedTypeAccessor.java:354)
          at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getString(GeneratedStatement.java:327)
          at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getString(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:882)
          at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$10.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:374)
        */

                      )

      org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.OuterScopes.addOuterScope(this)

      //TODO: parameters
      Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutils")

      val d: Driver = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      val jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
      val jdbcTable = "(select numval, decval, strval, dateval from info)" // we need to cut off "unsupported" columns
      val jdbcUser = "scott"
      val jdbcPassw = "tiger"

      val connectionProperties = new Properties()
      connectionProperties.put("user", jdbcUser)
      connectionProperties.put("password", jdbcPassw)


      //TODO: create context
      val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
        .master("local")
        .appName("Spark Oracle demo")
        .getOrCreate()

      import sparkSession.implicits._

      //TODO: start processing
      val df = sparkSession.read
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("url", jdbcUrl)
        .option("dbtable", jdbcTable)
        .option("user", jdbcUser)
        .option("password", jdbcPassw)
        .load()

      println("Info Oracle schema: ")
      df.printSchema()



      import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

/* does not work:
val ds = df.select($"NUMVAL".as[Long], $"DECVAL".as[Double], $"STRVAL".as[String],$"DATEVAL".as[Date]).as[Info]
*/

//workaround:
          val ds = df
            .withColumn("NUMVAL", df("NUMVAL").cast(LongType))
            .withColumn("DECVAL", df("DECVAL").cast(DoubleType))
            .withColumn("STRVAL", df("STRVAL").cast(StringType))
            .withColumn("DATEVAL", df("DATEVAL").cast(DateType))
            //.withColumn("TIMESTAMPVAL", df("TIMESTAMPVAL").cast(TimestampType))
            //.withColumn("TIMESTAMPLTZVAL", df("TIMESTAMPLTZVAL").cast(TimestampType))
            //.withColumn("NCLOBVAL", df("NCLOBVAL").cast(StringType))
            //.withColumn("XMLTYPEVAL", df("XMLTYPEVAL").cast(StringType))
            .as[Info] /* without "withColumn" there is an error:
          Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast `numval` from decimal(38,10) to bigint as it may truncate
            The type path of the target object is:
            - field (class: "scala.Long", name: "numval")
          - root class: "OraTest.Info"
          You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object;
          at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveUpCast$$fail(Analyzer.scala:2119)
        */    
          println("Info DataSet data: ")
          ds.show()    
          ds.printSchema()    
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post your case class and table schema? It would be helpful

Comment: @T. Gawęda, I've added the full example.